# How to trigger @State object with respect to ObservableObject Object?

Tags: ios, swiftui

This are two properties which I declared

```
struct DashBoardView: View {
    @State var isToPush: Bool = false
    @ObservedObject var sideBarHandler = SideBarHandler()
```

Where SideBarHandler is -

```
class SideBarHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isListItemClicked:Bool = false
}
```

Now I am looking to activate `$isToPush` based on `sideBarHandler.isListItemClicked`

Because I want to bind it here

```
 NavigationLink(destination: FavouriteView(), isActive: $isToPush) {// NavLink
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider where the source of truth is for the data.

Based on your description, it seems that the `isListItemClicked` ***is*** the source of truth, so you shouldn't even need a `@State` variable - use `$sideBarHandler.isListItemClicked` directly (prefix `$` of an `@ObservedObject` gives you a `Binding`):

```
NavigationLink(destination: FavouriteView(), isActive: $sideBarHandler.isListItemClicked)
```

---

Of course, if `@State var isToPush: Bool` is only affected by `sideBarHandler.isListItemClicked` but otherwise exists independently - i.e. it is a source of truth for this data - then you can use `onReceive` as suggested by @Asperi to change the `isToPush` property:

```
.onReceive(sideBarHandler.$isListItemClicked) { 
   isToPush = $0 
}
```

(note that `$` prefix here accesses a `@Published` Combine publisher)

---

Also, unrelated to your question, but if you're instantiating an `ObservableObject` inside the view, then you should use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`. The latter is meant for a case when the observable object is created outside of the view.

Comment: super cool I need to deep into StateObject could you give an example of it.

Comment: @Amit, it's used the same way as an `@ObservedObject`, except the view "owns" instantiating the object; so, in your example you should change it to `@StateObject var sideBarHandler = SideBarHandler()` because the view instantiates the object

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onReceive` somewhere in `body`, like

```
struct DashBoardView: View {
    @State var isToPush: Bool = false
    @ObservedObject var sideBarHandler = SideBarHandler()

    var body: some View {
       VStack {
          // some content here
       }
       .onReceive(sideBarHandler.$isListItemClicked) {
          isToPush = $0
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. could you please suggest any tutorial or link for learning "ADVANCED SWIFTUI" ?